# Unwanted spaces between span elements wrapped in divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, height, spaces

```css
span { background: green; }
```

```html
<div><span> Hello World      </span></div>
<div><span> Foo bared        </span></div>
<div><span> Ariovistus Dummy </span></div>
```

There are little unwanted spaces between the span elements. I want to remove them with CSS, but how do I do it?

Well after some inspection I found that `div` with some content has more height than `span` with the same content.

```js
let printHeight = tag => console.log(`The height of ${tag}: ${document.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0].getBoundingClientRect().height}px.`)

printHeight('div');
printHeight('span');
```

```html
<div>Hello World</div>
<span>Hello World</span>
```

And probably that is the reason for the spaces. But why is that? And how to remove the spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
span {
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div><span> Hello World      </span></div>
<div><span> Foo bared        </span></div>
<div><span> Ariovistus Dummy </span></div>
```

Edited!

Comment: In the original project, I have other content along with the `spans` in the `div`s, so I can't ditch the `div`s entirely. Any way to do it by keeping `div`s in their place?

Comment: It's working with the same html too if that's what you want

Comment: The `div`s which contain the `span`s have a purpose, so I can't remove them. In your answer you remove the `div`s, that I can't do. Maybe fix that?

Comment: Edited my answer